# Get all documents from elastic if key1=value1 and key2=value2 only if there doesn't exists another document where key1=value1 and key2=value3

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to retrieve certain documents using elastic's RestHighLevelClient for Java. Currently I need to retrieve documents based on certain criteria.

There are some trades, I have documents which have following information

`id = 1, status = SUCCESS`

`id = 2, status = SUCCESS`

`id = 1, status = CANCELLED`

Now I need to retrieve all trades which were successful but weren't cancelled.

Currently my approach is to get both Successful trades and cancelled trades separately in JAVA and then remove all trades that are cancelled from successful trades.

I use these queries to generate:

```
query1 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("status", "success"))

query2 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("status", "cancelled"))
```

And then generate

```
List<Trade> Success, List<Trade> Cancelled 

List<Trade> SuccessButNotCancelled
```

by looping both of them

Is there any way that I can get this lust by simply querying Elastic? If it is which one would be more efficient, my current approach or the new approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate your result by `status` field. So that in one shot you will have two data sets from elastic. One with `success` & one with `cancelled`.

For `SuccessButNotCancelled` you can use java logic on this two result set. I will say if your result size is very high then better to make another request to elastic to retrieve  `SuccessButNotCancelled`.
For that you can use the query as:

```
BoolQueryBuilder successButNotCancelled = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("status", "success"))
                    .mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("status", "cancelled"));
```

In this way in two elastic calls you retrieve:

```
List<Trade> Success; //in first call of aggregation
List<Trade> Cancelled; //in first call of aggregation
List<Trade> SuccessButNotCancelled; //using successButNotCancelled
```

Comment: your query for successButNotCancelled will always return just success results, because when status is success, status cannot be cancelled. There is a new entry where status is cancelled for that Id. so I have to do that match, your first approach of java logic is what I am already using!